# How to move all files plus hidden to folder down?

Tags: files, rename

I want to move all my drupal files in www folder to html folder. I don't know how to do this in terminal and I'm not sure if all folder and files including hidden ones are drupal in the www folder, is there a way of checking the lesser obvious ones or would www have been empty before and any hidden files will auto recreate?

Answer (score 3):

With zsh:

```
mv -- *(D) html
```

`mv` will complain that it can't move `html` to itself, but will still move the rest.

With bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv -- * html
```

With ksh93:

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
mv -- * html
```

POSIXly:

```
mv -- * .??* .[!.] html
```

or

```
mv -- * .[!.]* ..?* html
```

(you're likely to get errors for those of the patterns that have no match. That should be harmless but will still cause the exit status to be non-zero so in script you would not be able to distinguish that with a failure to move files).

Comment: Oh I wish I had seen this before- very helpful. I ended up uploading to html directory a fresh install and now the other is still residing other folder so I will just remove what I know to be drupal I guess. Thanks. I will copy this above info for future ref.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way:

```
# from the www directory
cd ..
mv www html
mkdir www
mv html www/
```

This assumes you don't already have a `html` directory at the same level as `www`. If you do, pick a different name:

```
cd ..
mv www temp_name
mkdir www
mv temp_name www/html
```

Comment: remember to check access permissions and ownership if you're to recreate a directory that existed before.

Answer (score 0):

A naive option (don't try it!) would be: `mv * .* html` - this will however try to move `.` and `..` too, which is not quite what you want. I usually do something like `mv * .??* html` - this moves normal file and hidden files with names that have at least 3 characters in them, effectively skipping `.` and `..`

Comment: That would skip `.a` and `.z` as well.

Comment: Thanks but how do I know what files are assoc with drupal, is there a way to ask the system?