# How to move files from parent diretory to sub-directory using command?

Tags: command-line

I want to move files from parent directory to sub-directory using command only. because i have only SSH access to remote server.

I have files on /var/www/html/ and i want to move to /var/www/html/myfolder

UPDATE: i somehow followed these steps was able to move files.

[Check this Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57272/195900)

Comment: yes googled but it shows how to move one directory up. but i want to move one directory down. And i'm using centOS for first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll bite. You use the `mv` command.
Say that you are in directory `foo`:

```
ls foo/*
foo/file1 foo/file2

foo/bar:
```

Now you want to move `file1` and `file2` from directory `foo` to directory `foo/bar`:

```
mv -v file1 file2 bar/
file1 -> bar/file1
file2 -> bar/file2
```

Result:

```
ls foo
bar
ls foo/bar/
file1 file2
```

**https://www.linux.com/learn/how-move-files-using-linux-commands-or-file-managers**